# how to make Spark avro reader stop infering type when reading a partition

Tags: apache-spark, types, hdfs, avro, partition

Trying to read an avro file partitionned by year month and day from hdfs .
I was expecting the partitions to be read as string but the type was infered to integer

So say i am reading avro files from hdfs that exists on a partitions year ,month and day .
Here is a sample:

val df = spark.reader.format("avro").load("Path_Till_Partition"/year=2023/month=02)
df.show()

When i open the dataframe i transforms the value of the col("month") to 2 instead of "02" and marks it as an integer .
Is there any way to make it read the partitions as Strings instead ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the conf :

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled", "false")

When type inference is disabled, string type will be used for the partitioning columns.